# Software to play Buzz games "manually"

Tags: windows, gratis, game

I have 2 Playstation [Buzz!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz!) USB controllers, so 8 people can participate in parallel. I also know that these buzzers can be connected to the PC.

Use case: I am doing trainings for all sorts of things (Wireshark, Debugging, ...) After a lesson, I'd like to perform a quiz with the participants. The participants can win small things, e.g. sweets. In the past, I did everything manually, but sometimes discussions arose who were the first to provide the answer. Since all the trainings are deep technical, I thought using the buzzers would be a nice gimmick.

I am now looking for a software that

- runs on Windows 7 x64 and Windows 10
- recognizes all controllers (support at least 2)
- allows the moderator to start a question (make the buzzers ready)
- finds out the first person that presses the buzzer
- play a sound when the first buzzer was pressed
- stops the question (puts buzzers on hold)
- highlights the buzzer of the person that pressed first (red light)

That's already it. I don't need support of the remaining 4 buttons, since answering the question will be handled by me.

I know [Buzzmania](http://sourceforge.net/projects/buzzmania/), but that's already too automated and I don't want to generate questions in advance. I could not make [You don't know JackBuzz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jackbuzz/) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I didn't think it would be that easy. I got everything up and running in 45 minutes using the [BuzzIO Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuzzIO) for .NET.

Here's a minimum application with no object oriented design whatsoever.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BuzzIO;

namespace BuzzExample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IEnumerable<IBuzzHandsetDevice> _handsets;

        static void Main()
        {
            _handsets = new BuzzHandsetFinder().FindHandsets();
            foreach (var handset in _handsets)
            {
                handset.SetLights(true, true, true, true);
                handset.ButtonChanged += HandsetOnButtonChanged;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void HandsetOnButtonChanged(object sender, BuzzButtonChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Buttons.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{i}: ");
                if (!args.Buttons[i].Any) Console.Write("None");
                if (args.Buttons[i].Blue) Console.Write("Blue ");
                if (args.Buttons[i].Green) Console.Write("Green ");
                if (args.Buttons[i].Yellow) Console.Write("Yellow ");
                if (args.Buttons[i].Orange) Console.Write("Orange ");
                if (args.Buttons[i].Red) Console.Write("Buzzer ");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            var lights = new bool[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Buttons.Length; i++)
            {
                lights[i] = args.Buttons[i].Any;
            }
            _handsets.First().SetLights(lights[0], lights[1], lights[2], lights[3]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hint for Windows 10: the controller might be installed as "HID-compliant game controller". In this case, the library may not find the connected controllers. To fix that, go to the device manager and switch the driver to "HID-compliant device". Mine has vendor ID (VID) 054C for Sony and product ID (PID) 1000.

For the Buzzer sound I used [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) and generated the following sound

- tone generator 2
- wave form: sawtooth
- frequency: 300 to 200 Hz
- amplitude: 0.8 to 0.8
- interpolation: linear
- duration: 0.2 seconds

For playing sound, you can use an embedded resource and a SoundPlayer:

```
 // Playing sound from embedded resource
 Stream buzzerStream = Resource.buzz;
 buzzPlayer = new SoundPlayer(buzzerStream);
 ...
 buzzPlayer.Play();
```